# Launcher activity with dialog when close it show apk icon not normal view

Tags: android, android-dialog

> Launcher Activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".module.lanuch.LaunchActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

with a dialog operate

```
mDialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this).customView(R.layout.layout_update, false).canceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        .show()
mDialog!!.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
mDialog!!.setOnDismissListener { onBackPressed() }

mContent = mDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.content) as TextView
mContent!!.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
mLastVersion = mDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.version) as TextView
mUpdate = mDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.download_install) as ShadowButton
mProgress = mDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.down_progress) as ProgressBar
mClose = mDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.update_close) as Button
mClose!!.setOnClickListener {
    if(mDialog!!.isShowing) {
        mDialog!!.dismiss()
        normalFlow(rightnow)
    }
}
```

when close dialog application shows a frame with apk icon then process normal flow, it's ugly, I do not like this frame. Can anyone explain why happen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code

```
  mClose!!.setOnClickListener {
    if(mDialog!!.isShowing) {
        mDialog!!.dismiss()
        normalFlow(rightnow)
    }
  }
```

to

```
    mClose!!.setOnClickListener {
        if(mDialog!!.isShowing) {
            mDialog!!.dismiss()
        }
    }
    mDialog!!.setOnDismissListener {
          normalFlow(rightnow)
    }
```